# Exception when Instantiate Array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have the object "Rootobject" as shown in my code.
I have a list “list_of_cars” of the object Cars  and I am trying to create a "Rootobject" that contains an array with the "Cars" list.
So I am instantiating an Rootobject and try to assign the array.The problem is that I always getting error “System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public PricingData data { get; set; }
    }

public class PricingData
    {
        public Cars[] cars { get; set; }
    }

public class Cars
    {
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
       public decimal price { get; set; }
    }
 Rootobject myobject = new Rootobject();
 myobject.data.cars = list_of_cars.ToArray();//here I am getting the error
```

Comment: You haven't initialised `data`, so you can't assign a value to it's child members.

Comment: omg you are correct. Thank you very much. Please post your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `Rootobject` contains an object of type `PricingData` which is not instantiated when you create your `Rootobject`

Try one of these solutions to instantiate your property when you create a `Rootobject`

```cs
public class Rootobject
{
    public PricingData data { get; set; } = new PricingData();
}

public class PricingData
{
    public Cars[] cars { get; set; } = Array.Empty<Cars>();
}
```

```cs
public class Rootobject
{
    public PricingData()
    {
        data = new PricingData();
    }

    public PricingData data { get; set; }
}

public class PricingData
{
    public PricingData()
    {
        cars = Array.Empty<Cars>();
    }

    public Cars[] cars { get; set; } 
}
```